# Show mysql result of one column in different columns

Tags: mysql, select, pivot-table, multiple-columns, rows

I'm new to mysql and currently stuggeling with a little weird problem,
I am faced with a list with three rows:

```
Customernr  Type    Amount
------------------------------
111         A           10
111         B            5
111         C           21
222         B           12
333         A           20
333         C           14
```

I need to format the output like:

```
Customernr   A   B   C
----------------------------------
111         10   5  21
222          0  12   0
333         20   0  14
```

I have tried it with multiple "if" clauses:

```
SELECT distinct `Customernr`,
IF(`Type`='A' ,`Amount`, 0)  as A,
IF(`Type`='B' ,`Amount`, 0)  as B,
IF(`Type`='C' ,`Amount`, 0)  as C,

FROM `database`
```

The result is:

```
Customernr   A   B   C
----------------------------------
111         10   0   0
111          0   5   0
111          0   0  21  
222          0  12   0
333         20   0   0
333          0   0  14
```

If I add a group by `Customern`

the result will display only the first value

```
Customernr   A   B   C
----------------------------------
111         10   0   0
222          0   0   0
333         20   0   0
```

Maybe my approach is totally wrong but I hope you can understand the problem, not all customers do not have all types but I need to display every customer in one row including all his amounts of types even if the customer does not have all types.

I have searched through stackoverflow and as this is my first post I hop I am doing everything right.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How many types do you have? It might not be feasible to have a column for each of many types. Do you use a scripting language to display the result?

Comment: For your searching pleasure, this is called *pivoting*. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySql.

Comment: Try GROUP_BY instead of DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Customernr,sum(temp.A) as A,sum(temp.B) as B,sum(temp.C) as C from(
SELECT  `Customernr`,
IF(`Type`='A' ,(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM test_db td2 WHERE TYPE='A' AND td2.Customernr=td.Customernr  ), 0)  as A,
IF(`Type`='B' ,(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM test_db td2 WHERE TYPE='B' AND td2.Customernr=td.Customernr  ), 0)  as B,
IF(`Type`='C' ,(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM test_db td2 WHERE TYPE='C' AND td2.Customernr=td.Customernr  ), 0)  as C

FROM test_db  td ) as temp GROUP BY Customernr
```

I got the result

```
111 10  5   21
222 0   12  0
333 20  0   14
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sumesh TG, this works as expected.
Thank you O.Jones for the "buzzword" for my research.
@Adder, I'm working with PHP/PDO/HTML Table for displaying results if there is a way for pivoting the results I would appreciate any additional hints.